# What happens if you don't include any activation function on hidden classification layers?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, convolutional-neural-network, activation-function

What happens if we don't apply an activation function to the classification hidden layers and apply it only for the final output layer (Sigmoid, Softmax)?

I'm asking this because I have trained a CNN with transfer learning and fine tuning, and in the final classification layers that are after the convolution layers of the base model I didn't include any activation layer except for the final one ('Sigmoid', it is a binary classification) and I got good results in the test set.

Is this something strange? It could happen?

Comment: Do you mean that you have convolution layers, multiple fully-connected layers, and then an output layer, and those multiple fully-connected layers lack activation functions?

Comment: Yes, sorry if I didn't explain myself well enough, but that's exactly what I wanted to ask.